# Why do sapply() and lapply() have same result?

Tags: r

I am new to R. I was practicing lapply() and sapply() function: lapply() returns list, and sapply() returns as vector/matrix. Now there I don't understand why do lapply() and sapply() have same result as a list?

```
> x1 <- lapply(list(1:3, 25:29), function(x) {2*x})
> x2 <- sapply(list(1:3, 25:29), function(x) {2*x})
> x1
[[1]]
[1] 2 4 6

[[2]]
[1] 50 52 54 56 58

> x2
[[1]]
[1] 2 4 6

[[2]]
[1] 50 52 54 56 58

> str(x2)
List of 2
 $ : num [1:3] 2 4 6
 $ : num [1:5] 50 52 54 56 58
> mode(x2)
[1] "list"
```

After, I checked unlist() and it return same input as a vector. 
It's hard to understand why do sapply() return list type as a result.

Thank you.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/4002530) is worth a read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `length` of the `list` elements are not the same, `sapply` will not coerce it to matrix and will have the same result as `lapply`

We can check the Usage of `?sapply` and `?lapply`

> lapply(X, FUN, ...)
>
> sapply(X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)

The `simplify=TRUE` is the one that converts a `list` of equal length output to a `matrix`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand! :D